# Does $3 < x+2 < 5$ $\implies$ $\frac{1}{5} < \frac{1}{|x+2|} < \frac{1}{3}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $3 < x+2 < 5$ $\implies$ $\frac{1}{5} < \frac{1}{|x+2|} < \frac{1}{3}$

If we bound $x$ by $1<x< 3$, then $x + 2 = |x+2|$. Is this correct?

Why do I ask this? Have a look at the following:

[image: example]

**Source**: [Example 7: Evaluating a limit using the definition](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Book%3A_Calculus_(Apex)/01%3A_Limits/1.02%3A_Epsilon-Delta_Definition_of_a_Limit)

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: This is correct, we can say this because $\frac1{x}$ is strictly decreasing for $x > 0.$

Comment: Yep.   If $3 < x+ 2 < 5$ then $x+2 > 0$ so $|x+2| = x+2$.  And if you have $0 < a < b$ you have $\frac 1a > \frac 1b> 0$ and so $3 < |x+2| < 5 \implies \frac 13 > \frac 1{|x+2|} > \frac 15$.   S'all good.

Comment: When you are analyzing this, I recommend taking the RHS inequalities one at a time.  I would approach as: $3 < (x+2) < 5 \implies 1 = (3-2) < x < (5-2) = 3.$  From here, you know that $x > 0 \implies (x + 2) > 0 \implies \frac{1}{|x+2|} = \frac{1}{x+2}.$  Then, to prove that $\frac{1}{5} < \frac{1}{x+2}$, you focus on $x < 3.$  To prove that $\frac{1}{x+2} < \frac{1}{3}$, you focus on $1 < x.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, if $1<x<3$ then this means $x>0$ $\Rightarrow$ $x+2 > 0$

if $x+2 > 0$ then $\mid  x+2 \mid = (x+2)$

Comment: Or simply $x+2 > 3 > 0 \implies | x+2 | = x+2$